# Referencing list items in templated task list

Tags: task-list, template, list-template

I'm currently looking at how make a task list templated, that all works fine and shows up as an app in the Add Apps area, however in the Task List I want to template there are columns where the content is a reference to another list on the site.

[image]

Is there a way to template a collection of lists as part of one application and maintain those relations?

The task list would be created on the same tenant and would be a on a subsite.

Comment: Where are you creating the new task list using template? In same SharePoint site?tenant where the referenced list is added? or in different site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap just updated the question to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly lookup list items have to be redone when using a template.  The template will not hold on to the relationships between the list items.  You will hve to delete the lookup values and re-enter them each time you use the template.

Comment: Sad that this limitation exists, but thank you for your answer.